# Can alfresco webscripts still be called after session time out?

Tags: session-cookies, alfresco, session-timeout, alfresco-share

What I am doing is I set both alfresco and share to session time out time 60 minutes in their web.xml file.

My scenario is

> 1. When I want to start a workflow in Start Workflow page, I fill all
>      necessary data but do  not click "Start Workflow" button.
> 2. After session time out, I click this "Start Workflow" button.
> 3. At the first time, authentication box opens and request for username
>      and password.
> 4. I filled user name and password of another user.
> 5. It starts a workflow with the authenticated another user.
> 6. Other times for session timeout, it does not request authentication
>      box, but acts for previously requested authenticated user.

So I think **Why does it happen??? Is it because of cookie??**

Currently there are four cookies used, namely alfLogin, alfUsername2, JSSESSIONID, _alfTest. Only when user is logged out, alfUsername2 cookie is deleted and others are remained.alfLogin and alfUsername2  cookies' expire time is 7 days and other cookie are depends on session.

**Can alfresco web script still be used after session timeout?** If so, how can I avoid this condition?

Comment: Do you perhaps have different timeouts for your Alfresco Repository sessions and your Alfresco Share sessions? That might explain the symptoms you're seeing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I have to answer my own question, I just want to share my result. I have to trace much. But answer is so simple.

Firstly, it is not because of cookie.

This answer is not only just for clicking "Start Workflow" button but also **calling alfresco webscript after session time out in share**.

All calling to alfresco webscript is done by `EndPointProxyController` specifically `org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.mvc.EndPointProxyController` in `spring-webscripts-1.0.0-sources.jar`.

In `handleRequestInternal` method if there is no session and basicHttpAuthChallenge is true, basic authentication box is shown as below.

```
            else if (this.basicHttpAuthChallenge || descriptor.getBasicAuth())
            {
                // check for HTTP authorisation request (i.e. RSS feeds, direct links etc.)
                String authorization = req.getHeader("Authorization");
                if (authorization == null || authorization.length() == 0)
                {
                    res.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_UNAUTHORIZED,
                            "No USER_ID found in session and requested endpoint requires authentication.");
                    res.setHeader("WWW-Authenticate", "Basic realm=\"Alfresco\"");

                    // no further processing as authentication is required but not provided
                    // the browser will now prompt the user for appropriate credentials
                    return null;
                }
                else
                {
// other coding
                }
```

We can avoid this condition as

> in `endpointController` of **slingshot-application-context.xml**, change
>   **basicHttpAuthChallenge to false.**

Like

```
   <!-- Override EndPointProxyController to enable Basic HTTP auth challenge on 401 response -->
   <bean id="endpointController" class="org.springframework.extensions.webscripts.servlet.mvc.EndPointProxyController">
      <property name="cacheSeconds" value="-1" />
      <property name="useExpiresHeader"><value>true</value></property>
      <property name="useCacheControlHeader"><value>true</value></property>
      <property name="configService" ref="web.config" />
      <property name="connectorService" ref="connector.service" />
      <property name="supportedMethods"><null/></property>
      <property name="basicHttpAuthChallenge"><value>false</value></property>
   </bean>
```